# Placing contents of ArrayList into PriorityQueue Java Issue

Tags: java, arraylist, nodes, priority-queue

I have the following code which is causing a problem:

```
List<Node> tempList=new ArrayList<Node>(); //baseline
//creation of another temporary list of type Node for temporary storage
List<Node> tempList2=new ArrayList<Node>();

List<Node> temp = Adjacency_List.get(current.dest);
for(Node node: temp){
    //testing
    System.out.print(current.dest + " - " + node.dest);
        System.out.println("\t\t("+Main.getEdge(current, node)+")");

    for(int i=0; i<tempList.size(); i++){
        //copying nodes from tempList into tempList2
        tempList2.add(tempList.get(i));
        System.out.println("TEMP LIST2 : "+tempList2.size());
    }

    tempList2.add(node);
    System.out.println("TEMP LIST2 SIZE : "+tempList2.size());
    cost=tempCost;
    cost+=Main.getEdge(current, node);
    n=new Node(tempList2, cost);
    pq.add(n);
    tempList2.clear();
}
```

This code's basic aim is to get the children of the current node (by using current.dest) and for each Node in temp, it copies the contents of tempList into tempList2 (tempList contains Nodes as well). The problem arises when after the contents of tempList2 are added to priority queue pq (pq.add(n)) and then cleared by using `tempList2.clear()`. The contents of tempList2 within the priority queue pq are also being cleared by this line. Is there a way I can clear the contents of tempList2 array list without simultaneously clearing the contents of tempList2 within the priority queue (previously added to the priority queue through the use of line pq.add(n);)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

## Solution 1

Add a copy of your list instead of the original list itself. The copy will remain unchanged after you `clear()` the original.
Change

```
n = new Node(tempList2, cost);
```

to

```
n = new Node(new ArrayList<>(tempList2), cost);
```

## Solution 2

It may be better (for both, efficency and readability) to create a new list instead of copying and clearing the same list in each iteration. Remove

```
tempList2.clear();
```

and move

```
List<Node> tempList2 = new ArrayList<Node>();
```

to the first loop's body, such that you create a new list in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

When you add `n` to `pq`, you're creating an *alias*: the List field of `n` you've added refers to the exact same instance that `tempList2` refers to.  It stands to reason that if you mutate that instance by calling `clear()`, your queue loses the elements as well.

There are 2 ways to avoid the alias:

1. Copy the list to a new list before inserting it, incurring a O(N) performance penalty on every insertion (where N is the length of `tempList`).
2. Create a new, empty list instance and assign it to `tempList2` instead of using `clear()` on each iteration, incurring a O(1) penalty.

I should point out that if `tempList` were ever non-empty, you would be wasting loads of cycles on copying it into `tempList2` using a loop with `get()`.  The `addAll()` method is generally more efficient.